# compulsive binding of this with functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through the code of jBox.js and came across the following lines of code:

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup.jBox-' + this.id, function(ev) {
    (ev.keyCode == 37) && this.showImage('prev');
    (ev.keyCode == 39) && this.showImage('next');
}.bind(this));
```

Have a look at the code **[HERE](https://github.com/StephanWagner/jBox/blob/master/Source/jBox.js#L300)** , this guy seems to compulsively bind functions with the value of `this`, I have a few questions regarding this pattern.

- Is this some kind of design pattern ?
- What is the author trying to achieve by binding most methoding with `this` ?
- For instance take the above snippet of code, what is the author trying to achieve by binding the function with `this`. (My guess is bind is functioning similar to jQuerys $.proxy here ? maintaining the value of this inside a new function definition.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code you showed, if you removed the `.bind(this)` call, then `this` within the `keyup.jBox-` handler would be set to whichever DOM node triggered the event.  The author, though, apparently wants `this` to be equal to whatever `this` is (probably the `jBox` instance?) at the point where the handler itself is created.

I don't know if I would consider this a "design pattern", it's just a language feature that allows the author to enforce that `this` is exactly what they want it to be, regardless of how the function itself is invoked.

> My guess is bind is functioning similar to jQuerys $.proxy here?

Yes, it's very similar.

<strike>Quick</strike> example:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greet = function() {
        console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name);
    };
};

var tenali = new Person('Tenali');
tenali.greet();
// > Hello, my name is Tenali
```

Great, this works, because I, as the author, expect you to always access this as `<person-instance>.greet()`. What happens if someone breaks that assumption, though:

```
var jeremy = new Person('Jeremy');
var greet = jeremy.greet;
greet();
// > Hello, my name is undefined
```

Obviously not working as intended, because now `greet()` is being invoked as a plain ol' function, completely detached from `jeremy` as the context target (which is normally inferred in JavaScript by the `.` notation used to invoke a method).

Now, as a consumer of the `Person` instance, you can still force `this` to be `jeremy` again by using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var jeremy = new Person('Jeremy');
var greet = jeremy.greet;
greet.apply(jeremy);
// > Hello, my name is Jeremy
```

...which is nice, but not exactly elegant. So, to make things easier on you, I could have instead *forced* `this` to be what I wanted it to be, as follows:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greet = function() {
        console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name);
    }.bind(this);
};
```

Now, if we go back to the earlier example, we'll see that it works as intended, as I've "bound" the `greet()` function to the Person instance already:

```
var jeremy = new Person('Jeremy');
var greet = jeremy.greet;
greet();
// > Hello, my name is Jeremy
```

Comment: That's weird. Methods can be invoked as normal functions in JS? That leads me to so many questions.